# Merging / gluing arrays

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I'm trying to merge / glue two arrays.

For example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\maybe}[1]{#1}
$\begin{array}{c}a\\b\end{array}\maybe{\begin{array}{c}\scalebox{10}{C}\\d\end{array}}$
\end{document}
```

This clearly doesn't work: The lines of the two arrays aren't aligned. I'd want it to behave as if it were `$\begin{array}{cc}a\maybe{&\scalebox{10}{C}}\\b\maybe{&d}\end{array}}$`. But I'd like to avoid having to add `\maybe` (which is here because I'll use the same code several times and sometimes I won't want to show this part) everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REVISED ANSWER, based on comments with the OP.  Since it was desired to modify the vertical spacing of earlier arrays, based on that of later arrays, the only feasible solution is to save the arrays, rather than rendering them, and then choose which ones to merge, at the end.

The logic uses the `\definearray{<label>}{<array>}` macro to define the component arrays that may or may not make it into the final array.  The macro uses the `listofitems` package to parse the cells of the array into `\array<label>[<row>,<col>]` indexed data.  Once all the arrays are defined, the macro `\mergearrays{<comma-separated-label-list>}` will combine the data from the arrays in the label list in the appropriate fashion.  That appropriate fashion requires a 3-nested loop of `<row>`-`<comma-separated-label-list>`-`<col>` in order to regurgitate the raw tokens in the proper `...&...&...\\...` form to be digested by a TABstack.

As one can see in the MWE, the vertical spacing adjusts so as to keep the baseline of each merged row aligned.

Note: done in text mode, but add `\stackMath` to change that.  Stacking gap set (here as 10pt) but can be adjusted to suit.  Likewise for intercolumn gap (currently 1ex).

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,listofitems,pgffor}
\newtoks\arraytoks
\newcommand\definearray[2]{\setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \expandafter\readlist\expandafter*\csname array#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\addtoarray[1]{\global\arraytoks\expandafter{\the\arraytoks#1}}%
\newcommand\mergearrays[1]{%
  \setsepchar{,}%
  \readlist*\arraylist{#1}%
  \arraytoks{}%
  \foreach\Row in{1,...,\expandafter\listlen\csname array\arraylist[1]\endcsname[]}{%
    \ifnum\Row=1\relax\else\addtoarray{\\}\fi
    \foreachitem\Arr\in\arraylist[]{%
      \ifnum\Arrcnt=1\relax\else\addtoarray{&}\fi
      \expandafter\foreachitem\expandafter\Col\expandafter\in%
        \csname array\Arr\endcsname[\Row]{%
        \ifnum\Colcnt=1\relax\else\addtoarray{&}\fi
        \expandafter\addtoarray\expandafter{\Col}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \expandafter\tabbedShortstack\expandafter{\the\arraytoks}%
}
\parskip 1em
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}
\begin{document}
\definearray{A}{a\\b}
\definearray{B}{\scalebox{10}{C}\\d}
\definearray{C}{e & g\\f & \scalebox{5}{H}}
Array A: \fbox{\mergearrays{A}},
\quad
Array B: \fbox{\mergearrays{B}},
\quad
Array C: \fbox{\mergearrays{C}}.\par
Merging A and B: \fbox{\mergearrays{A, B}}\par
Merging A and C: \fbox{\mergearrays{A, C}}\par
Merging B and C: \fbox{\mergearrays{B, C}}\par
Merging C, B and A: \fbox{\mergearrays{C, B, A}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works for arbitrary numbers of rows and columns, as long as each array shares the same number of rows.  Here is a 3-row example:

```
\definearray{A}{a\\\scalebox{2}{B}\\c}
\definearray{B}{\scalebox{7}{D}\\e\\f}
\definearray{C}{g & j\\h & \scalebox{4}{K}\\i& l}
Array A: \fbox{\mergearrays{A}},
\quad
Array B: \fbox{\mergearrays{B}},
\quad
Array C: \fbox{\mergearrays{C}}.\par
Merging A and B: \fbox{\mergearrays{A, B}}\par
Merging A and C: \fbox{\mergearrays{A, C}}\par
Merging B and C: \fbox{\mergearrays{B, C}}\par
Merging C, B and A: \fbox{\mergearrays{C, B, A}}
```

[image]

Comment: The baseline aligning is good but I'd also want the "cells" to automagically fit the size of the content. If I understand your code correctly, it doesn't and you have to manually specify the height with `\setstackgap`.

Comment: @xavierm02 The problem is that the `ab` array does not and cannot know in advance the layout of `Cd` and so cannot automagically adjust if they are defined as two separate arrays.  Put them in a single TABstack, and then, sure, it can be done.

Comment: @xavierm02 For example, this will work: `\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\maybe}[1]{#1}
$\tabbedShortstack{a&\scalebox{10}{C}\\b&d}$
$\tabbedShortstack{a&d\\b&\scalebox{10}{C}}$
\end{document}`

Comment: So there's no way to have a magical `\glue` operation so that `\glue{\begin{array}{l}1\\2\end{array}}{\begin{array}{c}3\\4\end{array}}` behaves just like `\begin{array}{lc}1&3\\2&4\end{array}`?

Comment: @xavierm02 What could be done (might not satisfy your need) is to save the desired contents (i.e., tokens) of individual columns, and then at the end, assemble them.  into a matrix/array/stack.

Comment: @xavierm02 The other thing that could be done directly (but would I think look ugly) is to make all rows at the large height, regardless of whether the row contained large or only small data.

Comment: Well saving the content and then making an array with it looks hard so I hopped there was already something available. It would be way easier if I wanted to erase some lines but I want to erase columns... But I couldn't find a way to transport an array either...

Comment: @xavierm02 `tabstackengine` saves the data for the most recent stack, which can be recalled cell by cell.  It uses the powerful `listofitems` package to parse the input and save into arrays.  you should look at their documentation, but I'll see if I can cobble something together to give the gist.

Comment: @xavierm02 Done.  It was fun.